# Find and Remove Lines in a file by comparing multiple strings

Tags: bash, macos

I have the following file:

```
SOME TEXT AT START OF FILE
    STRING1 SMALL
    STRING2 SMALL
    STRING1 MEDIUM
    STRING3 LARGE
    STRING2 XLG
SOME TEXT TO SEPARATE LISTS
    STRING4 SMALL
    STRING1 MEDIUM
    STRING1 SMALL
    STRING5 LARGE
    STRING6 SMALL
SOME MORE TEXT TO SEPARATE LISTS
    ANOTHER LIST
...
```

For each list, I only want to keep the largest (S,M,L,XL) occurrence of each string so that the result would look like this:

```
SOME TEXT AT START OF FILE
    STRING1 MEDIUM
    STRING3 LARGE
    STRING2 XLG
SOME TEXT TO SEPARATE LISTS
    STRING4 SMALL
    STRING1 MEDIUM
    STRING5 LARGE
    STRING6 SMALL
SOME MORE TEXT TO SEPARATE LISTS
    ANOTHER LIST
...
```

I have no idea how to do this.  Please help.  I am trying to do this in a bash script through terminal on a mac.

---

I also need to modify another similar list

```
TEXT
    STRING1
    STRING2
    STRING3
    STRING1
TEXT
    STRING4
    STRING1
TEXT
    STRING5
    STRING2
    STRING5
ETC...
```

How do I eliminate the duplicate strings in this case?  I was going to try to use `awk '!seen[$0]++' filename`, however this would remove the string from each list instead of looking at each list separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    sz["SMALL"]  = 0
    sz["MEDIUM"] = 1
    sz["LARGE"]  = 2
    sz["XLG"]    = 3
}

/^[^ ]/ {
    dump()
    delete data
    print
    next
}

!($1 in data) || sz[data[$1]] < sz[$2] {
    data[$1] = $2
}

END {
    dump()
}

function dump(k) {
    for (k in data)
        print "    " k " " data[k]
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
SOME TEXT AT START OF FILE
    STRING1 MEDIUM
    STRING2 XLG
    STRING3 LARGE
SOME TEXT TO SEPARATE LISTS
    STRING4 SMALL
    STRING5 LARGE
    STRING6 SMALL
    STRING1 MEDIUM
SOME MORE TEXT TO SEPARATE LISTS
    ANOTHER LIST
...
```

And for the second one

```
awk '/^[^ ]/{delete seen}!seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried it out and everything works great unless the STRINGS are preceded by something that is not a space.

Comment: Sorry - I was cut off from editing my last comment.... Typically the lines with STRINGN and SIZE would begin with some additional text so that STRING would end up being $6 instead of $1 and SIZE would end up being $7 instead of $2.

The problem is when I print everything at the end, it does not print the first line correctly:

SOME TEXT
FIND SOME MORE TEXT STRINGN SIZE
FIND SOME MORE TEXT STRINGN SIZE <-- DUPLICATE to remove
FIND SOME MORE TEXT STRINGN SIZE

becomes

SOME TEXT FIND SOME MORE TEXT STRINGN SIZE
FIND SOME MORE TEXT STRINGN SIZE

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly, so we can help